# Magento reorder function

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have been trying figure out past 3 days but in vain, iam looking to send a reminder email to customers to reorder their previous purchase. Magento reorder function works with logged in customers with `www.yourdomain.com/sales/order/reorder/{order_id}` which adds the items from their previous orders to their shopping cart. But if the customer is not signed in it redirects to a guest form. i want to load items from a previous order to their shopping cart even if they are not logged in. so when customer clicks a link, he is then redirected to the `checkout/cart` page with all items from their previous order. i tried using the following code

```
<?php
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$orderId= '2986';
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$cart->init();
$cart = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code for create order based on order id, You can make a link with this order id,

For this you can make an observere before load cart page.

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(2); // 2 is order entity_id
 $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

 $items = $order->getItemsCollection();

 foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
                if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($e->getMessage());
                }
                else {
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e,
                    Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.')
                );

            }
        }

$cart->save();
```

Comment: it throws an error stating customer session already exist. i then added $cart->init(); above $items = $order->getItemsCollection(); and it worked. Thank you very much for help.you saved my day @InfoBeans

Comment: Its my pleasure.